# Elasticsearch Version 6.5.4 wrong number of available processors

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question about how Elasticsearch detects the available processors. Here is what I got:

```
"os" : {
"refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
"name" : "Linux",
"arch" : "amd64",
"version" : "4.4.0-87-generic",
"available_processors" : 1,
"allocated_processors" : 4
}
```

The availabe_processors shows as 1. But in elasticsearch.yml, I use env $NUM_PROCESSORS (which is 4) to override this value

```
processors: $ {NUM_PROCESSORS: 1}
```

But looks like this doesn't works. I have versions, 6.5.4 has the issue but 6.2.4 doesn't. I searched around but couldn't find anything helpful here.
Could anyone share some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Figured out this issue by adding 
`-XX:-UseContainerSupport`
in Java options.

It's only affect with Java version > 10, which is using by ES 6.5.4
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html#JDK-8146115